# php echo to html with jquery fade effects

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to echo php to html, everything works fine but the echo stays on the page until refresh it goes away. anyway I can use jquery to fade in, out it?

part of the php coding:

```
$q1=mysql_query("SELECT `DEALS` FROM `show` LIMIT 1");
$d1=mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$n2=$d1['DEALS'];
if($n2!=0){

foreach($addresses as $to) { 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
echo'<center><span class="text-wrapper-2 text-wrapper-green">Email Sent!
</span></center>';
}
else{

echo'<center><span class="text-wrapper-2 text-wrapper-red">Email Failed</span></center>';    
}
```

so the code above echo correctly to html but I would like to add some jquery face effects to it. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: The jQuery code would be client-side, nothing to do with your PHP.  The PHP code echoes all of the output to the page, some of which can be styled to not be visible and then faded in with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't have any, that is what I want to add. I am not good at jquery

Comment: Thanks david, I guess I would need to echo to a string then use jquery in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript interaction happens entirely client-side, after the PHP is done.  So essentially you'd echo the output and then do the client-side effects.  So let's say you echo something like this:

```
<span class="text-wrapper-2 text-wrapper-green" id="emailMessage" style="display:none;">Email Sent!</span>
```

Note that I added an `id` to the element to make it easy to identify.  I also gave it an in-line style to not display, since you want it to fade-in first.  Feel free to move that styling into CSS as appropriate.

Then in your client-side code you might have something like this:

```
$('#emailMessage').fadeIn(400, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#emailMessage').fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
});
```

This will fade the element in and then set a timer to fade it back out 5 seconds later.

Comment: I tried this but it did not display anything. maybe I am doing something wrong?. here is what I have. php echo'<center><span class="text-wrapper-2 text-wrapper-green id="emailMessage" style="display:none;">Email Sent!</span></center>'; and html as you coded above

Comment: @user3303594: You have a typo, you didn't close the quotes for the `class` attribute.  You might also want to check your JavaScript console for any errors, debug the code to make sure the jQuery selector finds the element you expect it to, etc.  For example, if you don't even have jQuery loaded then it will fail with a console error, which you won't see on the page.  Or if you try to run the code before the element is even loaded then it will "silently" fail by just not finding the target element.

Comment: woops, :) works likes a charm. Thank you so much. really appreciate it. what is strange console did not display an error. but never the less working great.. Thanks so much once again

Comment: @user3303594, __you should accept this answer as correct__.

Answer (score 2):

wrap that into a div tag with a class you can select,

```
<div class="someClass" style="display:none">  your code here </div>
```

and have a script tag and put your javascript here

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.someClass').fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

then echo that code

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way to do it. But do an ajax call to your php script and then display your results as you fade them in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.buttonPush').on('click', function() (

            if (!$(this).hasClass('pushed'))
            {
                $('.buttonPush').addClass('pushed');

                $.ajax('/link/to/php/page', {


                }).done(function(data) {

                    $('.myElem').html('your html').fadeIn();

                    $('.buttonPush').removeClass('pushed');
                });
            }
        ));
    });
</script>

<div class="myElem">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, this works as well but since I am using a crm this will require additional coding. David's request above works perfictly